# Ther axis of Imported FBX from 3ds Max into Uity 3D is not matching because of which object is not moving desired direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, axis, 3dsmax

I have created 3d model in 3DS Max and imported in Unity 3D.
In Unity 3D i m moving object in `-Z axis` direction.
While exporting object from 3ds max axis are `x0, y0, z0` and in FBX settings `y-axis up`.

When model imported in the Unity 3D object appear as rotated in `x-axis 90 degree`

code is working fine its moving the object in `-z zxis` but object is rotated in `X90`.

And when I rotate my FBX object in required position then object is moving downwards in `-y axis` direction.

[image: Object in 3ds Max]

[image: FBX option]

[image: Imported FBX in Unity 3D]

[image: Object moving the different directions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I just figured out the problem.

In 3DS MAX, change the pivot point of the object then export.

First, Y - axis was facing Front view and Z - axis top [image 1]

```
Rotate X - Axis with 90 degree
```

Now Y - axis id pointing top and Z - axis is pointing back [image 2]

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very useful max script
http://www.strichnet.com/improving-the-fbx-workflow-between-3ds-max-and-unity3d/

or my tweaked version (ui fix, success alert disabled)
https://yadi.sk/d/HKMDxakf3a3zHq

may not work with animation and rigged models
example of settings
[image]